# Meteor Iron Router error : has no method 'go'

Tags: exception, meteor, iron-router

After inserting a record into a collection in a server side method I route to a different named route.  But I get an error : "has no method 'go'".

```
Meteor.methods({
  'create_item': function (item) {

    Items.insert(item, function (error,result){
      if(result){
        Router.go('dashboard');
      }
    });
  },
});
```

The route changes successfully and the page renders the dashboard template, but I get the following error.

> I20160526-12:00:15.662(3)? Exception in callback of async function:
>   TypeError:  Object function router(req, res, next) {
>
> I20160526-12:00:15.662(3)?     router.dispatch(req.url, {
>
> I20160526-12:00:15.662(3)?     //XXX this assumes no other routers on
>   the parent  stack which we should probably fix
>
> I20160526-12:00:15.662(3)?       request: req,
>
> I20160526-12:00:15.663(3)?     }, next);
>
> I20160526-12:00:15.662(3)?       response: res
>
> I20160526-12:00:15.663(3)?   } has no method 'go'
>
> I20160526-12:00:15.663(3)?     at lib/methods.js:17:16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably defined method on shared area (e.g. `lib` directory), so on the client it works correct, but on the server side there is no such function as `Router.go`.

You should return result from method and then call `Router.go` on *client* side code.

On the server:

```js
Meteor.methods({
    'create_item': function (item) {
        //Insert blocks on server side,
        //no need to use callback
        return Items.insert(item);
    },
});
```

On client side:

```js
Meteor.call('create_item', item, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        Router.go('dashboard');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Ramil I had a feeling that it was unavailable on the server side. But Meteor Methods are exposed to the Client so i figured it might work.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Ramil.

In the end I discovered it was the lib could not be found on server side. I also discovered the AutoForm hooks - which is a much smarter way to run the post insert code.

I attached this hook to the Iron Route (well the Iron Route Controller to be exact)

```
onRun: function () {
    AutoForm.hooks({
      createItemForm: {
        onSuccess: function(){
         Router.go('dashboard');
        }
      }
    });
    this.next();
  },
```